# Any advantage of static over non static for simple function

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is just to satisfy my curiosity. Is there any difference or advantage of doing one of these over the other

```
public static void Save(Guid id, int a, string b)
{
     //Save a and b to the database using PK id
}
```

OVER:

```
Guid ID {get; set;}
int A {get; set;}
string B {get ;set;}

public void Save()
{
    //Save A and B to the database using PK ID
}
```

EDIT:
Okay some context: So Web UI passes JSON to static Page Method. Page Method parses JSON and passes new variables to static class in other DLL. This then uses entity framework to update database. Is this okay?

Comment: I think you're missing some state in the sample--the database connection or information.  I don't think your first method could really be static.

Comment: You now have seven different answers to this question, many of which say "it depends" or "I would prefer". Some swear by making it an object always. I also remember [Rich Hickey](https://twitter.com/richhickey) talking about how in Java he would ALWAYS use static methods for everything (he went on to later create [Clojure](http://clojure.org/)). I feel pretty comfortable saying that there isn't a "right" answer to this question. See also [this question on the programmers stack exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/98083/cant-i-just-use-all-static-methods) for more ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I would absolutely prefer the instance method over the static one.  The reason being that the static method means you have necessarily introduced global mutable state into your system.  In order to function the static method would need to access a database connection of some sort and do so statically.

Global mutable state should be avoided whenever possible.  It is a looming bug farm and hampers future changes to your code base (like introducing multiple threads).

Answer (score 1):

The example you've given seems to indicate you're writing some kind of persistence API, for which I'd strongly recommend using instantiable classes. Using static methods is okay for things like utility classes, but you'll rapidly find your code becomes unextendable and unmaintainable if you over use static mehods.

Answer (score 0):

Really, it depends on the situation you are using the method in.

For example, if you're implementing a command pattern, and you don't want to instantiate an object every time, a static method might be useful.

Likewise if you're just adding some functionality to a class, there really isn't any point making the method static.

Neither of these mean one is **better** than the other. It just means they have different uses. A gun is a phenomenally useful piece of kit, but not when you're trying to turn off the TV. See my point?

Comment: But if I had both in one class there would be absolutely no difference between them if one piece of code set the properties and called the non-static one, and another piece of code passed in the parameters to the static one? For example in performance (or anything)?

Comment: If you set fields, THEN call the non-static method then it would probably be slower, but I don't see what's wrong with just padding the non-static method some parameters either. I see your question though. Logically, a static method might be quicker because you never need to create the object in the first place. Overall, that will speed up execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Sealed functions are always preferred to unsealed, as the JITTER can (choose to) inline the former. Static functions are always sealed, as are all methods in sealed classes. However, avoiding copying properties onto the static is also preferred.

So as Chris says above, you need to decide on a case-by-case basis. 99% of the time it won't matter because performance is good enough, or the bottleneck is somewhere else, so keep the code clean.

Comment: I don't think "sealed" is relevant here.  By default, neither static nor instance methods are virtual.  (key word there: `virtual` -- you need to add that to the (instance) method signature to participate in polymorphism and "unseal" your function)

Comment: @Kirk: Yes, in retrospect my answer is less profound than it seemed at the time.

Answer (score 0):

That is basically "advantage of OOP vs. structural programming". In your case, the database connection would make all the difference: It can be field of the class, and you can provide it once in the constructor. The methods can use it if they need to.
With static methods, you'd need to provide everything in the parameters, even stuff that is always the same.

Methods that don't depend on the internal state of the object should be static.